# Sets and Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just a quick question. I am new to set theory and I have encountered a question I am unsure of that has to do with sets and cartesian products. Here is the question:

```
True or False: (6,7) ∈ {{6},4} X {{7},5}
```

My original thoughts were that this is false, because (6,7) is not the same as ({6},{7}) that would be produced, but I am unsure. Is this the right thinking?

Comment: I like your thinking

Comment: @J.W.Tanner great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is correct.  The answer is `False`.

$\{6\}$ is not the same as $6$, for example.